# Active admin sub menu problme

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, menu, activeadmin, submenu

I am unable to create submenu of submenu

Like

Parent
->
 Child1 ->A
          B

Child2

Like this

```
menu.add label: "Parent", url: "" , priority: 3  do |widgets|
    widgets.add label: "Child1", url:"", priority: 1 do |A|
       A.add label: "A", url:""
       A.add label: "B", url:""
    end
    widgets.add label: "Child2", url:""
end
```

Comment: What is the problem here? Any error message, something looks different than expected?

Comment: Not any error menu overriding other menus